# How can I get the current mercurial changeset revision not the hash

Tags: mercurial

I need to get the current mercurial changeset to return in a **very simple webservice**, just the incrementing revision number and not the hash.
I know I can use

```
 hg --cwd C:\repos\MyRepo parent
```

which will return me

```
changeset:   730:9d347e4a8d47
tag:         tip
user:        Simon Martin <simon.martin@mydomain.com>
date:        Tue Jun 12 15:39:45 2012 +0100
summary:     Fixed defect #244...
```

What I need though is just the 730 part of the changeset. The goal is to be able to write a very simple web service that will return that value - this will then be picked up by another application and displayed in the footer to give a quick reference as to which *local* revision is current. The testing process can then refer to that 'build' which can then be used to identify that.

Comment: Please make sure you understand that those *local* revision numbers are very local.  It's entirely possible that when someone clones the repository that they get the same changesets in a different order and thus the numbers can't uniquely identify a build anywhere except in that specific clone.

Comment: Absolutely, I recognise this is an edge case but I explicitly need a readable revision (hence the title). The repo that will be used is a deployed site, **nothing will ever** clone from it and there is only 1 path to it - from a master repo via a build server.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can show the local revision number of the working copy’s current parent using:

```
hg identify --num
```

Note that this outputs a `+` suffix when there are local changes. Add an `-r .` option to avoid this.

You can use the `-r` option to get the local revision number for other revisions too. For example, to retrieve the ID of the last tagged ancestor:

```
hg id -n -r "ancestors(.) and tag()"
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I like:  "hg id -i" to get just the tip changeset id.

Answer (score 15):

You can use a custom template for the `hg parent` command.

This should get what you want:

```
hg parent --template "{rev}"
```

Comment: How and where do I set up the custom template?

Comment: It’s specified right there on the command line, no need to set anything up. Another template example: `--template "Local revision number: {rev}\n"`.

Comment: Some documentation describing this feature is available here: http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html